# Disallow Uncheck all on a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, checkbox, checkedlistbox

my checkedlistbox has one condition: **Exactly one item has to be checked**.
That means changing the check the previous item has to be unchecked. That works. **But unchecking should not be able**. By looking at the GUI after try of uncheck the item is still checked due to the second condition in the ItemCheck-Method. Its not possible to uncheck the current check, how it should be. But after leaving the ItemCheck-Method the count of checked items is changing from 1 to 0 (Property CheckedItems), even though I can see the checked item. Something is missing in my code:

```
      private void myCLB_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
      {
         // 1. Checking one will uncheck all other, works perfectly
         if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked && myCLB.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
         {
            myCLB.ItemCheck -= myCLB_ItemCheck;
            myCLB.SetItemChecked(myCLB.CheckedIndices[0], false);
            myCLB.ItemCheck += myCLB_ItemCheck;
         }

         // 2. Unchecking without checking another not allowed
         if (myCLB.CheckedItems.Count > 0 &&
             myCLB.CheckedItems[0].Equals((sender as CheckedListBox).SelectedItem))
         {
            e.NewValue = CheckState.Checked;
            return;
         }

         // ... do some business here, depending on the check
      }
```

Btw: Using radiobuttons is no option as there is the possible need to use more than one checks. In this case the above constraints will be disabled.
I've tried also other variations of the second conditions, which worked also, except that always CheckedItems.Count is changing from 1 to 0 after the ItemCheck-Method is left. I didn't find a validate-method.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: you are boxed in arent you with *`Exactly one item has to be checked`*  that should mean they cant uncheck the last one and cant check the one they really want because there is already one checked.  Rather than micromanage the user at the click level, why not check how many are checked when they click Done/ok/Submit and tell them whats wrong

Comment: They can check whatever they want and exactly one is being checked all the time. This is the condition and this is what the user is seeing. He can change the check but unable to uncheck. Thats perfect, but _CheckedItems_ has a count of 0 even there is one checked. So I can't find out which is checked.

Comment: think about it...once one item is checked there is no way to check a different one without violating the rule.

Comment: interesting idea but the user should be able to change his decision. Depending on the check a view is showing a result. So the user will have to decide to stick with the check or change it.

Comment: I've done it now with checking the SelectedItem instead of CheckedItem. Don't know whether it's a misunderstanding on my side or prob in the control but this works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Plutonix suggests, you should consider checking how many are actually checked when the user submits the form. If the user has boxes A and B checked, but later wants boxes C and D checked instead, it'd be very natural for the user to want to uncheck A and B, then check C and D. Your current design doesn't allow this.

But, if you're *really* boxed in on this, I'd consider setting an `Enabled` property to `False` when the form is loaded or a checkbox is modified.  So if any of the checkboxes have been modified, you'll check if only one is checked, and if so, lock that one down.

Comment: the design doesn't allow this because it's not intended to check more than one. That part is working perfectly. Why should I disable the checkedlistbox at the start or after the user has modified the check? I want the user to be able to use the checkedlistbox instead of seeing it disabled.

Comment: I don't understand.  You say  "Btw: Using radiobuttons is no option as there is the possible need to use more than one checks," but at the top in bold, "Exactly one item has to be checked."  Which is it?

Comment: yes, on top of the current implementation I want to add this behavior. In this case the first condition would be disabled, then more than one can be checked. So this is already done with no loops or disabling the control. The only prob left is how do I say the control in the second condition to keep the checkeditem with state checked.